# What is the role or PSPRCSQUE in Peoplesoft Process Scheduler?

Tags: peoplesoft

Can some one tell me what ii the role of PSPRCSQUE. I don't find much information about it when i look at the Process Scheduler Architecture they mentioned only about the PSPRCSRQST table and how it works but nothing about the PSPRCSQUE table and its role in Peoplesoft Process Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

The PSPRCSQUE table holds information needed to schedule the request and to check that it is still running. When the process is initiated, the operating system process ID of client process is stored in SESSIONIDNUM. [This column is updated with 0 when the process was submitted by user.] The information from this table is needed if the process scheduler needs to kill the process.

See following website for a clear overview on the workings of the Process Scheduler:
http://peoplesoftsa.blogspot.be/p/process-scheduler_30.html

Comment: Thank you Robin Debruyne. It's really help full.